# Copy corresponding files instead of initialising new ones

Tags: python

I would like to initialise an object in Python by loading and/or copying several internal dataframes for several cases (that are contained in a list: `["case1", "case2", "case3", "case4"]`. Initialising these dataframes can be time-consuming, so if there is a dataframe available for another case with the same settings, I would like to copy that dataframe instead of initialising a new one. The cases that correspond to each other are stored in a dictionary: `{"case1": ["case1", "case2", "case3"], "case4": ["case4]"}`, i.e. I combine all grouped cases in a list and use the first entry as key. Now this is easy if I want to perform operation if I have loaded all the dataframes already because I can loop over the keys to perform an operation and then copy the results to all corresponding cases in the list and avoid performing the same operation twice for different combinations of settings.

However, it becomes more challenging when I want to load existing files. Say I want to initialise the object with dataframes for all four cases, and I have the necessary dataframes for "case2" and "case4" stored in files. That means that I only need to load those two and I can get the dataframes for "case1" and "case3" by copying "case2". However, I am completely lost as to how I need to do this.

I started like this:

```
# Store which cases are loaded
matching_cases_dict = {"case1": ["case1", "case2", "case3"], "case4": ["case4]"}
unavailable_cases = ["case1", "case2", "case3", "case4"]
available_cases = []

# Loop through cases
for case in cases:
   target_file = os.path.join(folder, case)
   if os.file_path.exists(target_file):
      # Function to load file
      unavailable_cases.remove(case)
      available_cases.append(case)
```

Then I run into trouble when I try to copy the dataframes to the corresponding cases:

```
if unavailable_cases:
            for unavailable_case in unavailable_cases:
                for key, matching_cases in matching_case_dict.items():
                    for matching_case in matching_cases:
                        if matching_case == unavailable_case:
                            if matching_case in available_cases:
                                data[unavailable_case] == data[matching_case]
                                available_cases.add(unavailable_case)
                                unavailable_case.remove(unavailable_case)
```

As my object will still initialise two identical dataframes...

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Full code, maybe the issue is somewhere else:

```
def load_data(data, reconstruction, reconstruction_name, reconstruction_times, type, all_cases, all_options, matching_case_dict, topologies, rotations, files_dir):
    # Loop through times
    for reconstruction_time in reconstruction_times:
        data[reconstruction_time] = {}
        # Initialise list to store available and unavailable cases
        unavailable_cases = deepcopy(all_cases)
        available_cases = []

        # If a file directory is provided, check for the existence of files
        if files_dir:
            for case in all_cases:
                file_path = os.path.join(files_dir, f"{case}_{reconstruction_name}_{reconstruction_time}.csv")
                if os.path.exists(file_path):
                    data[reconstruction_time][case] = DataFrame_from_csv(files_dir, case, reconstruction_time, reconstruction_name, type)
                    unavailable_cases.remove(case)
                    available_cases.append(case)
                else:
                    print(f"DataFrame for {type} for {reconstruction_name} at {reconstruction_time} Ma for case {case} not found, checking for similar cases...")

        # Copy dataframes for unavailable cases
        for unavailable_case in unavailable_cases:
            print("Unavailable: ", unavailable_cases)
            print("Available: ", available_cases)
            for key, matching_cases in matching_case_dict.items():
                for matching_case in matching_cases:
                    if matching_case == unavailable_case:
                        if matching_case in available_cases:
                            data[reconstruction_time][unavailable_case] = data[reconstruction_time][matching_case].copy()
                            available_cases.add(unavailable_case)
                            unavailable_cases.remove(unavailable_case)
                                
                if unavailable_case not in data[reconstruction_time]:
                    print(f"Initialising new DataFrame for {type} for {reconstruction_name} at {reconstruction_time} Ma for case {unavailable_case}...")
                    if type == "Plates":
                        data[reconstruction_time][unavailable_case] = get_plates(topologies, rotations, reconstruction_time, 1, all_options[unavailable_case]["Anchor plateID"])
                    if type == "Slabs":
                        data[reconstruction_time][unavailable_case] = get_slabs(reconstruction, reconstruction_time, all_options[unavailable_case]["Slab tesselation spacing"])
                    if type == "Points":
                        data[reconstruction_time][unavailable_case] = get_points(reconstruction, reconstruction_time, all_options[unavailable_case]["Grid spacing"])
                    available_cases.append(unavailable_case)
                    unavailable_cases.remove(unavailable_case)

    return data
```

Comment: `case1 = case2.copy()`?

Comment: I don't want to copy the case itself, I want to copy the dataframes associated with case2 to case1...

Comment: I didn't read the question carefully, I thought that was the variable with the dataframe. Just replace it with the correct variable.

Comment: But I don't know which cases are available. So if I have case1 but not case2, case2 should be copied from case1 and vice-versa.

Comment: So use `if` statements? I'm not really sure I understand the question, since you sometimes refer to files and other times refer to dataframes.

Comment: Have you looked at my code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I first needed to find the dictionary key to the list that contains the unavailable case, and then loop through those to see if any of the other cases in that list are available. I tried to combine these two in one loop, which didn't work. Solution below:

```py
# Copy dataframes for unavailable cases
for unavailable_case in unavailable_cases:
    matching_key = None
    
    # Find dictionary key of list in which unavailable case is located
    for key, matching_cases in matching_case_dict.items():
        for matching_case in matching_cases:
            if matching_case == unavailable_case:
                matching_key = key
                break
        if matching_key:
            break

    # Check if there is an available case in the corresponding list
    for matching_case in matching_case_dict[matching_key]:
        # Copy DataFrame if found
        if matching_case in available_cases:
            data[reconstruction_time][unavailable_case] = data[reconstruction_time][matching_case].copy()
            available_cases.append(unavailable_case)
            break
        
        # Initialise new DataFrame if not found
```